# What is wrong if my espresso pours out slowly but the first drops shoot out?

Tags: espresso

I've recently bought my first espresso machine (a Rancilio Silvia). I'm now trying to dial it in, but don't know how to interpret the result:

My shot is not too fast (it does not splash out of the machine). It also takes about 5 seconds until coffee starts pouring out. However, the coffee does not flow as evenly as I was expecting. The first drops really shoot out of the machine and then turn into a quivering stream of coffee. In the end, the cup is not clean at the rim but rather a bit sprinkled with coffee drops.

Did I tamp too hard or why does this happen?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Coffee SE! Nice question. It may be helpful to mention what kind of a machine you have.

Comment: @IvanKapitonov Thanks, I've edited the question.

Comment: Can you post photos of the coffee puck? That can be very useful for diagnosing.

Comment: Indeed - a picture of the spent puck still in the portafilter after your brew (e.g., [this dialing-in article](http://www.home-barista.com/tips/dialing-in-new-espresso-machine-step-by-step-guide-t3113.html)). See [this Serious eats article on dialing-in](http://drinks.seriouseats.com/2012/04/coffee-jargon-what-is-dialing-in-espresso-long-waits-at-coffee-shops.html) -- specifically, start with determining the best *coarseness of grind*. Pre-infusion might account for the delay; portafilter bottom style might affect splatter... but let's start with the grind!

Comment: Great picture! I gave a preliminary answer below, but... what else have you tried? Have you varied (one parameter at a time!) your dose weight or grind coarseness? How does the shot taste?

Comment: @hoc_age I'm currently keeping everything roughly the same except for the grind coarseness. The shots where first very sour and are now a bit to bitter (but have already improved a lot).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you've got *too much ground coffee* in the basket. What's the weight that you're using? It looks like the recommended dose for the stock basket is 14g, which is a bit lower than the "standard" of 19g or so.

You have an indentation (ring) around the outside of the grounds -- an indentation from the group/dispersion screen (in addition to the notorious protruding center screw on this model). If you're already tamping thoroughly, this could mean you've got too much coffee in there.

Here's a thread [from Home-Barista on the Silvia](http://www.home-barista.com/tips/puck-indentation-with-stock-rancilio-silvia-portafilter-basket-t16349.html) around a similar topic. It discusses another way of diagnosing the dose -- inserting the PF with tamped grounds, then removing while still dry.

That article also talks about aiming for a dose+tamp to leave a bit of space between the tamped grounds and the screen: approximately the thickness of a 5-cent piece of space (1-2mm), which is a general recommendation (not just for this machine), though there is certainly disagreement on this. Another article from [Serious Eats discusses this topic](http://drinks.seriouseats.com/2012/07/coffee-tools-the-espresso-tamper-how-to-tamp-correctly-barista-tips.html) and notes that a "sludgy mess" can result, because the grounds will expand a bit when they absorb water. Your picture also looks a little "wet"; it could just be the picture, or perhaps a similar symptom.

Try a lower dose (14g) and do the dry-removal test, aiming for a bit of space between the top of the tamped grounds and the screen.

Comment: I hope others have other ideas, too...

Comment: Thanks, I will try what you suggest. I was thinking that the indentation from the screw can probably not be avoided, and I just didn't notice the outer ring before. The puck is indeed a bit wet, but not super-soupy.

Comment: Turns out I was alreay putting in about 14g each time. But I noticed that the machine vibrates quite a bit (the cups start moving around).

Comment: Yes, the 'wetness' in the picture really shocked me. Does this machine not have a backflush valve?

Comment: @luserdroog It does have one. Turned out the problem was the coffee and the grind, and also this overfilling to some degree - everything is fine now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Over fill grind basket loosely then skim off excess grind. Tamp grind to 30 PSI, fairly stout push, make sure grind around perimeter is pressed also. Give a finial press and twist. The size and consistency of grind is important too. My grind is almost the right size, but the first 2 seconds it is liquid-y but quickly transforms to a thick foamy look which is what you want. If it is liquid-y throughout the run the grind is too coarse. Note: I happened to have .001 thick brass shim and was able to place shims under my grinders stationary plate in order to finer grind.